What does 'spin-adapted' mean?
I've seen this term everywhere but I haven't actually seen an explanation for what it means. I've seen it be applied to operators or other quantities, such as a density matrix $\rho(x, x')$, or wavefunctions ("spin-adapted configurations").
This may be more of a chemistry question but yeah. What does 'spin-adapted' mean?

Does it not just mean that the ansatz are chosen to satisfy a certain spin configuration, so that the theorist's smart choices would make the computation converge to the correct result much faster?

If you see it everywhere, you should perhaps give a pointer to one (or two) of those examples...
